# Strange uwsgi mountpoint for my django site with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I hit a strange issue with my site(nginx1.7+uwsgi2.0+django1.6).

Today I see there are some strange log entries in my uwsgi logs. 
Snippet here:

```
Mon Aug 31 10:43:17 2015 - WSGI app 1 (mountpoint='zc.qq.com|') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xf627c0 pid: 18360
zc.qq.com {address space usage: 421933056 bytes/402MB} {rss usage: 102522880 bytes/97MB} [pid: 18360|app: 1|req: 1/7] 61.132.52.107 () {42 vars in 684 bytes} [Mon Aug 31 10:43:17 2015] GET /cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.6131902049963026 => generated 0 bytes in 6113 msecs (HTTP/1.1 301) 4 headers in 210 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
zc.qq.com {address space usage: 421933056 bytes/402MB} {rss usage: 102522880 bytes/97MB} [pid: 18360|app: 1|req: 2/8] 61.132.52.105 () {44 vars in 986 bytes} [Mon Aug 31 10:43:29 2015] GET /cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.1676001222494321 => generated 0 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 301) 4 headers in 210 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
```

Actually, zc.qq.com is nothing to do with my site.
So, how this guy comes into my server? 
It sits here as an wsgi app, so, sometimes keep restarting together with my own django app, thus, sometimes it takes django app more than 5 secs to respond to http request.

I see the pid for strange app is 18360. So, here:

```
[root@localhost uwsgi]# ps -ef|grep uwsgi
root     18352     1  0 10:40 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18353 18352  0 10:40 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18354 18352  0 10:40 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18355 18352  0 10:40 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18356 18352  0 10:40 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18357 18352  0 10:40 ?        00:00:12 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18358 18352  0 10:40 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18359 18352  0 10:40 ?        00:00:13 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18360 18352  1 10:40 ?        00:00:18 uwsgi -x /home/uwsgi/uwsgi2.xml
root     18871 18818  0 11:07 pts/2    00:00:00 grep uwsgi
```

It comes from uwsgi...But here is uwsgi config file:

```
<uwsgi>
  <socket>/var/run/uwsgi.socket</socket>
  <listen>100</listen>
  <master>true</master>
  <vhost>true</vhost>
  <no-site>true</no-site>
  <pidfile>/usr/local/nginx/uwsgi.pid</pidfile>
  <processes>8</processes>
  <profiler>true</profiler>
  <memory-report>true</memory-report>
  <enable-threads>true</enable-threads>
  <logdate>true</logdate>
  <limit-as>6048</limit-as>
  <daemonize>/home/django.log</daemonize>
</uwsgi>
```

And, here is snippet in nginx.conf(domainname is just sample here)

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name www.mysite.com;
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass   unix:///var/run/uwsgi.socket;
            include     uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /home/mysite;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi;
           access_log  off;
        }
        location /static/ {
        root            /home/mysite/;
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
        autoindex on;
    }
 }
```

So, exactly nothings in any config files related to zc.qq.com or other strage domains(I also see proxyjudge.info).

Anyone hit this before?

Thanks.
Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have enabled virtualhosting and dynamic apps but you do not make any check from the nginx side. The first request for a non-configured (in uWSGI) domain, will result in a new app to load

Comment: Hi roberto, yes, I enabled virtualhosting, but what do you mean that not checking from the nginx side? It's not enough by the server_name? Could you please explain a little more detailed?

Comment: if you have a single host in nginx it will be the default one too. A common setup is having a catch all host triggering errors for not-configured hosts

Comment: I add a default_server to handle all not-configured hosts.